# Shopify APP embedded in C# .NET Windows Forms App Developer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, shopify

does anyone have experiences in embedding shopify app in C# .NET Windows Forms? I want to embed "Order printer" and "DPD integration" shopify apps to my Windows Forms application. Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have with WooCommerce...what is realy your doubt?